# Compartilhamento de imagem de um listview com Intent

Tags: android

Galera me ajudem pfv, bom é o seguinte . tenho uma listview com varias imagens e dai quando o usuário seleciona uma imagem na lista no app, essa imagem é atribuida a um ID no caso `R.id.ivCar` e na hora de passar a referencia na intent tá dando erro pq nao pode passar id com referencia tem q passar a imagem. bom como faço isso?
segue o codigo..

```
int resId = R.id.iv_car; // car.getIMAGEMRESOUCEID()
Uri uriToImage = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                                "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(resId));
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.app_name)));
```

me ajudem pfvvvvv... já fiz de tudoo a

Answer (score 0):

Para passas dados para um intent selecionado  de um listview   eu fiz desse jeito

```
ltsunidades.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View view, int posicao, long id) {
        Tab_UC obj = (Tab_UC) adapter.getItemAtPosition(posicao);
        String filial = "" + obj.getCod_UC();

        Preferencia.setfilial(Selecionar_Unidade.this, filial.toString().trim());

        Intent it = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Empresa.class);
        it.putExtra("Filial", filial);
        startActivity(it);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + filial, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

No meu caso estou pegando um código que preciso de um select feito em php  via web service e já estou salvando o mesmo em um sharedpreferences..